# Sub-plotting issue using Matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

My dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

store_num = [2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 19, 23, 24]
store_location = ['Free Standing', 'Strip Mall', 'Strip Mall', 'Strip Mall', 'Strip Mall', 'Big Box', 'Strip Mall', 'Strip Mall', 'Big Box', 'Big Box']
sales = [870859, 365501, 581628, 522831, 336361, 352152, 543373, 628040, 414274, 302452]
df_copy_cat = pd.DataFrame({'store_num': store_num , 'store_location' : store_location ,'sales': sales})
```

I want to make an EDA using subplots to show highest revenue of stores, best selling menu...etc.
I create the following code but the result shows 2 plots....
What am I doing wrong ?

```
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
df_copy_cat = df_copy[['store_num', 'sales', 'store_location']]
df_copy_cat = df_copy_cat.groupby(['store_num', 'store_location']).sales.sum()
df_copy_cat = df_copy_cat.reset_index().set_index('store_num')
df_copy_cat.sort_values(by = 'sales',ascending = False).plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot result is here]

Also tied the following code:

```
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
df_copy_cat.sort_values(by = 'sales',ascending = False).plot(kind = 'bar')

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
df_copy_cat.groupby('store_location').sales.sum().sort_values(ascending = False).plot(kind='bar')

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
county_sales.sort_values(ascending = False).plot(kind='bar')

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
best_seller.plot(kind='bar')
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing one plot, using pandas' `df.plot()` method. So you don't need the line `plt.subplot(2,2,1)`.

If, on the other hand, you want to do four subplots in one figure, you could do that in this way:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

df_copy_cat.sort_values(by = 'sales',ascending = False).plot(kind = 'bar', ax=ax[0, 0])
df_copy_cat.groupby('store_location').sales.sum().sort_values(ascending = False).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[0, 1])
county_sales.sort_values(ascending = False).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[1, 0])
best_seller.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[1, 1])
```

Note the `ax=...` arguments being passed to matplotlib via `df.plot()`.

Evidently pandas relies on matplotlib's object-oriented interface, so this works better than the `pyplot`-based approach.

Comment: Thanks, I now think you have to use the object-oriented method. I edited my answer to show how.